# How to isolate click event handler between parent and child elements in vuejs

Tags: semantic-ui, vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I'm trying to convert semantic-ui component to rely on vuejs instead of jQuery, but I don't know how to isolate v-on:click between child and it's parent element.

In this example below, I'm using v-on:click with a button which will show dropdown menu using a toggle function and there's another v-on:click assigned to delete icon, which will trigger another function.

The problem is, while I'm clicking on the delete icon, the dropdown menu will show-up.

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
`https://jsbin.com/minezij`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stop`  [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to stop the propagation of the event to parent elements.

```
<!-- the click event's propagation will be stopped -->
<a v-on:click.stop="doThis"></a>
```